# subtract corresponding column of a dataframe from a single row dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe with several columns and rows

```
df1=
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 
---------------------
  1   |   3  |   5
  3   |   4  |   8
  2   |   4  |   2
```

and another dataframe with a single row

```
df2=
col_1 | col_2 
-------------
  1   |   2
```

I would like to subtract the value of the corresponding column of the second dataframe from all rows in the first one. I could do it with

```
for col in df2.columns.tolist():
   df1[col] = df1[col] - df2[col].to_numpy()[0]
```

so the result would be

```
   col1 | col2 | col3
---------------------
     0  |   1   |  5
     2  |   2   |  8
     1  |   2   |  2
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
df1=df1.sub(df2.iloc[0],axis=1).fillna(df1)
Out[364]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0    0.0    1.0    5.0
1    2.0    2.0    8.0
2    1.0    2.0    2.0
```

Or `reindex_like`

```
df1-df2.reindex_like(df1).fillna(0)
Out[367]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0    0.0    1.0    5.0
1    3.0    4.0    8.0
2    2.0    4.0    2.0
```

Or via `numpy` value

```
df1[:]=df1.values-df2.reindex(df1.columns, axis=1,fill_value=0).values
df1
Out[376]: 
   col_1  col_2  col_3
0      0      1      5
1      2      2      8
2      1      2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

A cool way doing this:

```
(df1[['col_1', 'col_2']] - pd.concat([df2] * df1.shape[0], ignore_index=True)).join(df1['col_3'])

   col1  col2  col3
0     0     1     5
1     2     2     8
2     1     2     2
```